# Cycles render flickering object only when animated keys

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

Hello I have a problem with my project, while viewing a rendering sequence I realized that an object flickering only at a precise moment, when it is animated manually by keyframe.

http://prod.comparlimage.com/ID_logistic/Flickering.mp4

You can see, the box don't flickering during the curve animation, but when i put keys for move the box with the character, it start flickering.

[image]

[image]

[image]

All object in my scene are linked, I thought it might come from there, so i have make a real box for this exemple, but the bug still.

I also have this problem in another place in my scene with a single object that is just animated with keys, simple Z translation :
http://prod.comparlimage.com/ID_logistic/Flickering02.mp4

I have a simple environnement map, and many large area light.

I use Blender 3.0, Cycles X

I know the different cases that lead to flickering, my object is simple, no double vertex, normal out, simple diffuse material...

This is the first time I've seen this problem, if anyone has seen something similar or has an idea.

Thank you very much

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Well, although it appears to be extremely visible with keyframed animation, I see other things flickering there as well... how many samples do you use for rendering and is denoising enabled?

Comment: I have reset first link with a full quality clip 1920*1080 for you see. I use 128 render sample and open image denoise. The strange thing is that it is only these objects that flickering and only when they are animated by translation.

Comment: Just an idea, but what about rendering again (maybe just a few 10 or 20 frames where the flickering is very strongly visible) with let's say 500 samples or 1000 samples for comparison? And maybe with denoising turned off?